# Paypal button code to an email (link)

Tags: html, paypal

*Hello, 
I have tried to make a button which will open PayPal payment from C# winform, and i watched some tutorials, also created my button, but that gives me a html code **how could i get that code to a link?***

Answer (score 0):

When you create a hosted button on PayPal along with html code email link is also generated. You can use that.

I am attaching screenshot for your reference[image]